# How to use git mergetool with Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: git, merge, cloud9-ide

In my development team we started using Cloud9 IDE some time ago and discovered that it is inconvenient to use git mergtool with Cloud9.

In my offline setup I use meld as mergetool and that works great for me. The standard mergetool for Cloud9 is **vimdiff** which normally wouldn't pose a big problem.  However the vimdiff command to switch windows (**Ctrl-W**) also closes my window.

I can think of a few workarounds like:

- Map the vimdiff comand to another key combination
- Skip merging and do the merging by hand in the editor
- Use a different mergetool

I have the feeling that there should be an easier solution or a different mergetool. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I managed to use your first approach you mention. Follow the three tutorials starting here: [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*%28Part_1%29](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

That should help you to set it up as you wish. Good luck!